Is "Plan what you will do when" a full sentence? What does it mean? Can "when" and "what" switch places?
I read a suggestion

"Plan what you will do when"

I thought the full sentence is

"You plan what you will do when you will do".

Why what is "when" not followed by other words>
and how different is this from

"Plan when you will do what"


Plan what you will do when is fine, but your You plan what you will do when you will do is not syntactically valid. The original can be paraphrased as Plan what you will do and when you will do it (which kinda implies you're only going to plan and do one thing). OR as Plan when you will do the thing[s] you plan to do

plan=imperative. Like: Drink that coffee.

Constructs like yours of the what-when form are highly conventional in English, and part of that convention is that the when always follows the what. For example, What will you be eating and when? sounds perfectly natural (to this native speaker of American English), whereas When will you be eating and what? seems quite odd.
The phrase what you will do when, strongly suggests that the speaker understands which things will be done, and that the only thing in question is their sequence (or times or dates).

I'm not convinced either sequence is inherently "less idiomatic" between asking What will you be eating and when? and When will you be eating and what? But it's interesting to note that whereas OP's You plan what you will do when you will do is unquestionably ungrammatical, switching the order there to You plan when you will do what you will do is a syntactically valid (albeit quirky) utterance.

In any case, one needs and and: [...]and when?

The question asks if To plan what you will do when can be a full sentence. Possibly. It has the sense of planning a schedule; this is what you will do at each point of time. However it's not the way I would say it. I would say "plan what I will do and when." Thus the planning covers two related elements: what and when.
You will see the difference more clearly if I explain my first response on reading the OP sentence. I thought, "when what?" In other words, I thought you hadn't finished the sentence. I was reading when as a conjunction introducing a new idea, but where was the idea? I expected something along the lines of "We should plan what we will do when the family gets together for Dad's big birthday party."
Depending on context, another possibility might be to plan what you will do then. (ie, at that time)
